# Перевод реальных координат в пиксельные

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi, яндекс-карты

В блоге, вот тут https://yandex.ru/blog/mapsapi/40335 , довольно подробно расписан процесс перевода реальных координат в глобальные пиксельные координаты.

Воспроизвожу алгоритм оттуда и для широты 90.495707 у меня возвращается отрицательное значение. Это возможно?

Ранее был уверен, что пиксельные координаты всегда положительные.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Просто широты 90.495707 не существует.